# É seguro utilizar media queries agrupadas?

Tags: css, css3, media-queries

Todos os tópicos que encontrei em relação a media queries agrupadas são de alguns anos.

Com a grande variedade de CSS3, as consultas de media queries agrupadas agora são consideradas seguras de usar na produção?

Algum navegador que suporte o CSS3 suporte totalmente consultas de media queries agrupadas? Ou isso nem sempre seria o caso? Nesse caso, quais navegadores não suportam consultas de mídia aninhadas?

Exemplo de consulta de mídia aninhada para ilustração:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        body {
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bernardo Segue uma dica. Pela orientação W3C seria possível sim usar as @media aninhadas. Como vc pode ver na documentação oficial:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#processing

Porém para evitar problemas com o Browser o que se ve é usar dessa forma:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* seu CSS */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px) 
and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* seu CSS */
}
```

Aqui tem outra opção de aninhamento de @medias de diferentes tipos

```
@media screen and (min-width: 35em),
       print and (min-width: 40em) {
  /* seu CSS */
}
```

No site www.caniuse.com vc pode consultar e ver que apenas o IE não aceita o Aninhamento

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Também sugiro a leitura da documentação da Mozilla*

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@media

E aqui tem um artigo Sobre **Media Queries com Sass** que pode te ser útil também

https://css-tricks.com/approaches-media-queries-sass/ (em inglês)